# GAMS - matrix row operations

Tags: gams-math

I have the following matrix in GAMS (call it a matrix x with rows
i and columns j):

[image]

I wish to transform this by summing elements in the same column from
row 2 and row 1, and then setting row 2 to 0:

[image]

If an element of the original matrix x can be called $x(i,j),$ how
can I tranform it to look like this second matrix? Any help is much
appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, through trial and error, I managed it. If row 1 is entitled "1", and column 1 is entitled "1" and so on, I would do:

```
 x("1",j)=x("1",j)+x("2",j)

  x("2",j)=0
```